# 2 forms validate in same page - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have 2 forms in same page with jquery validation, but one of them is not working all the time.

the first one is ok with this code :

```
 $("#btnStep1").click(function() {
    var $form = $("#FormRegStep1");
    validator = $form.validate();   
    if ($form.valid())
  {
  }
  });
```

and this is the second one:

```
 $("#btnStep2").click(function() {
    var $form = $("#FormRegStep2");
    validator = $form.validate();   
    if ($form.valid())
  {
  }
  });
```

the second is ok except $form.valid.

what can be the problem ?

thank you

Comment: This is quite impossible to answer from the posted code, but wild guess, it's because the `validator` variable is global, and it should be `var validator = $form.validate();`

Comment: Then the second form probably isn't valid, or you're using the wrong selector etc. It's impossible to diagnose the issue from the posted code?

Comment: Should be initializing validation plugin outside the click handler in the first place

Comment: What @charlietfl said.  Review [the documentation for the plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info) to see how to properly use the `.validate()` method.